# How OSGi interface become known to the gateway?

Tags: osgi

I have this question that keeps popping up and looking through my notes and slides I cannot seem to find the answer.

The question that's been asked is:

"In OSGi, how does a bundle make its interfaces known to the gateway. How is 
this information used by the gateway"

I understand the principles of OSGi framework but I'm not sure how the interface becomes known.

Any help would be really appreciated :)
Thanks :)

Comment: Haha, Googled OSGI for revision of PSD and this came up. Tim Storer making my life hell -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the [Service Registry](http://www.osgi.org/About/Technology#Framework).  Providers register their services, and consumers get their services from this facility.

It is an implementation of something called a [Whiteboard Pattern](http://www.osgi.org/wiki/uploads/Links/whiteboard.pdf), the gist of which is that providers and consumers don't directly interact or depend on each other.  They have their offerings and requirements satisfied by a mutual 3rd party via published contracts (i.e. the interfaces).